# how to display text in edit text in the list view

Tags: android

My team and I are making an android chat application. We want to display the messages sent by the users in a `ListView`. How can we display the text entered in an EditText in the list view. Or is there any other way to achieve our goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the custom list view. In the custom list view use the custom adapter in which you can take an edit `TextView`. You can see this how to implement custom list view [here](http://www.rorraja.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-use-listview-using-custom.html). In this list view a `TextView` is used but you can replace this `TextView` with `EditText` view.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what type of adapter you're using to back the view. If you're using an `ArrayAdapter`, just add the text to the array each time you have a new message you want to display (for instance, every time a button was clicked). If you're using a `CursorAdapter`, you'd then have to add the text to the `ContentProvider` that the `Cursor` is viewing. Beyond that, I can't tell you much else. We'd need more details about what you're doing in order to answer any further.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with some different by your needs. I just get the editText values to my database and printed into EditText. Just see this code -

```
EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b.setVisibility(1);     
    output = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    output1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    String s1= output1.getText().toString();

    this.dh = new DataHelper(this);        

    this.dh.insert(s1);

    List<String> names = this.dh.selectAll();


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



    sb.append("Names in database:\n\n");
    for (String name : names) 
    {
       sb.append("\t - \t" + (name) + "\n");
    }

    this.output.setText(sb.toString());
```

Just change this with your needs. Try out using [this](http://www.ziddu.com/download/18617313/A.zip.html)